# Ubuntu passing command line arugments to C program

Tags: c

I am learning C programming, I wrote the sample code to accept parameters from terminal and print out the arguments.

I invoke the program like this: ./myprogram 1

I expected 1 to be printed out for the argument length instead of 2. why it is so? There was no spacing after the argument "1"

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    printf("%d", argc);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first argument, `argv[0]` is the name with which the program was invoked. So there are two arguments and the second, `argv[1]` is "1".

#### EDIT

Editing to make clear: `argc` should always be checked. However uncommon, it is perfectly legal for `argc` to be 0. 
For example on Unix, `execvp("./try", (char **){NULL});` is legal.

Comment: @Dr Deo Not always, I think C99 supports the concept of a program without any argument whatsoever.

Comment: @cnicutar - C *89* allowed for `int main()` instead of `int main(int argc, char **argv)`

Answer (score 2):

"./myprogram" counts as the first argument.